# Javascript function return result of a function differently in chrome for different instances

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

First i executed the below script in chrome console

```html
var x = 1; if (function f(){}) { x += typeof f; } x;
```

I got '1undefined' as result.

Then i executed function f(){} in console and again executed the above script,then i got the result '1function'.
Now i opened another instance of chrome browser and again run the above script i am getting '1object'.

My question is why i am getting different result.

step1:- Run the above code snippet in chrome console. Result is 1undefined

step 2:-Run function f(){} in chrome console.Result is 1function

step 3:-open another instance of chrome and run the above snippet again.Result is 1object

below that 1object ..i have this text 'Application Cache Checking event'

Comment: And how exactly did you execute `f()` ?

Comment: i copy paste the result of console.... var x = 1; if (function f(){}) { x += typeof f; } x;
"1undefined"
function f(){}
undefined
var x = 1; if (function f(){}) { x += typeof f; } x;
"1function"

Comment: another instance result ..var x = 1;
   if (function f(){}) {
     x += typeof f;
   }
   x;
"1object"
newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8:1 Application Cache Checking event

Comment: Are you sure you're not running this on a page that defines a variable called `f` elsewhere on the page? The correct result is `"1undefined"`, since `if( function f(){} )` here is a named function *expression*, which does not create a variable identifier in the current scope. When you run `function f(){}` by itself, it's a function *declaration*, which *does* create a variable called `f` in the current scope.

Comment: You should edit your question to show clear instructions of what you did to produce your result. Please don't put long strings of code in comments, because they don't show up well. Instead, you can [edit] your question.

Comment: when you open a new tab, `window.f` is a reference to the form element wrapping the google search input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open another tab of chrome, it by defaults open Google home page. If you execute the script there from console even for the first time, it will print 1object. As there is a javascript file on that page that define a variable F as object. You can check it here https://www.google.co.in/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8

As most sites minify js files, the variable are named A,B.....

Its not magic :)